# I broke yum -- Can't do anything

Tags: centos, yum

I was trying to follow a tutorial for installing yaffas (zarafa-admin) and I went to install the packages and got failed checksum errors for EVERY mirror.  So after about 15 mirrors, I just hit CTRL+C to stop yum.

```
Now when I run yum anything, I get the following error:
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. $releasever is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/$releasever/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Can someone please help me fix this?

My resolv.conf is working fine.  I can connect to the internet and ping anything.  The issue happened after I hit CTRL+C to break the current yum run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem after hours and hours of searching.  I found a post somewhere that indicated that the $releasever variable was not expanding quickly and they hardcoded their distroverpkg in the /etc/yum.conf file.

I looked at this file and it was set to:  centos-releasea

It should have been:  centos-release

I fixed the typo and all started working again!

Answer (score 1):

Try running `yum clean metadata` followed by `yum makecache fast`

This happens occasionally when the metadata is corrupted but yum thinks it's correct.

Comment: When I had all those mirrors failing, I think yum automatically set all the repos to enabled=0.  I went through and set all repos to enable=1 and then I already ran #yum clean all.  I just did what you asked and ran:  # yum clean metadata and that showed 0 metadata files removed.  I then ran:  # yum makecache fast and got the exact same error as above.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out, that would have been hard to diagnose on SF...